# tag gives error :crypto.rand_bytes/1 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I added the login_as tag to my tests and phoenix started giving that exception:

```
defmodule Rumbl.VideoControllerTest do
  use Rumbl.ConnCase

  setup %{conn: conn} = config do
    if username = config[:login_as] do
      user = insert_user(username: username)
      conn = assign(conn(), :current_user, user)
      {:ok, conn: conn, user: user}
    else
      :ok
    end
  end

  @tag login_as: "max"
  test "list all user's videos on index", %{conn: conn, user: user} do
    user_video = insert_video(user, title: "funny cats")
    other_video = insert_video(insert_user(username: "other"), title: "another video")

    conn = get conn, video_path(conn, :index)
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ ~r/Listing Videos/
    assert String.contains?(conn.resp_body, user_video.title)
    refute String.contains?(conn.resp_body, other_video.title)
  end

  test "requires user authentication on all actions", %{conn: conn} do
    Enum.each([
      get(conn, video_path(conn, :new)),
      get(conn, video_path(conn, :index)),
      get(conn, video_path(conn, :show, "123")),
      get(conn, video_path(conn, :edit, "123")),
      put(conn, video_path(conn, :update, "123", %{})),
      post(conn, video_path(conn, :create, %{})),
      delete(conn, video_path(conn, :delete, "123")),
    ], fn conn ->
      assert html_response(conn, 302)
      assert conn.halted
    end)
  end
end
```

It's complaining at line 15, which is the @tag login_as: "max" line, it was working before the tag

mmm I am not sure what this error means with rand_seed because I am not using any crypto function:

> 1) test list all user's videos on index (Rumbl.VideoControllerTest)
>        test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:15
>        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :crypto.rand_bytes/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:
>
> ```
>        * rand_seed/0
>        * rand_seed/1
>
>  stacktrace:
>    (crypto) :crypto.rand_bytes(8)
>    (rumbl) test/support/test_helpers.ex:8: Rumbl.TestHelpers.insert_user/1
>    test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:6: Rumbl.VideoControllerTest.__ex_unit_setup_1/1
>    test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:1: Rumbl.VideoControllerTest.__ex_unit__/2
> ```

test_helpers.ex source:

```
defmodule Rumbl.TestHelpers do

  alias Rumbl.Repo

  def insert_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
    changes = Dict.merge(%{
      name: "Some User",
      username: "user#{Base.encode16(:crypto.rand_bytes(8))}",
      password: "supersecret",
    }, attrs)

    %Rumbl.User{}
    |> Rumbl.User.registration_changeset(changes)
    |> Repo.insert!()
  end

  def insert_video(user, attrs \\ %{}) do
    user
    |> Ecto.build_assoc(:videos, attrs)
    |> Repo.insert!()
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `test/support/test_helpers.ex`?

Comment: posted, there it is the crypto function :P but dont know why it complains with the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:crypto.rand_bytes/1` [was deprecated in OTP 19](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/1ad18832cb21fac5a5b513005f1e6a5ffd7d0329) and [later removed in OTP 20](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/a30254355bc9798348471878009b6e063ad26fca). You can use `:crypto.strong_rand_bytes/1` instead:

```
...
username: "user#{Base.encode16(:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(8))}",
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error, I am following this Programming Phoenix book which might be outdated https://www.amazon.es/Programming-Phoenix-Productive-Reliable-Fast/dp/1680501453